# Show that if mean of $X_i = m,$ Then $P(\frac{X_1 + \ldots + X_n}{n} < m/2) \to 1$ as $n$ is large.

Tags: probability-theory

So mean of $X_i = m, Var(X_i) = \sigma^2.$ I tried to use Weak Law of large numbers but can't seem to finish it.

I want to show that $P(\frac{X_1 + \ldots + X_n}{n} - m/2 > 0) \to 0$, which is an equivalent statement. The 2 below $m$ is throwing me off. Any hints?

I put it together to get

$$P(\frac{2 \sum X_i - \sum E(X_i)}{2n} > 0)$$ but dont see how this helps. Thanks!

Comment: This is actually false: as a counterexample  take $X_i=1$ constant.

Comment: This is completely false as it contradicts the strong law of large numbers. Where did you get such a statement/problem?

Comment: Unless $m<0$...